# make webgl canvas transparent

Tags: javascript, canvas, shader, webgl

I want to make my webgl canvas transparent but the thing is that I pick the code on codepen: [here](https://codepen.io/DedaloD/pen/MWEpbZz) and saw the same on a forum and they were also debating on how to change the color, but there wasn't any answers.

The only things that I said is that writing `canvas.fillStyle = "#ffffffff"` didn't work, as `gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)`. They said that the color comes from the shaders but I'm quite new to webgl and I don't really understand how shaders works for now.

I also looked at this question: [How to make Webgl canvas transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273858/how-to-make-webgl-canvas-transparent) and it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vUv);
```

This line is states that fragColor witch is vec4 gonna be colored by sampled texture.

Basically you can think about vec4 in this case as an RGBA vector, so if you do something like:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

at this pixel color gonna be black but not transparent

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Would be a white but transparent pixel

So by doing this:

```
 gl_FragColor = dissipation * texture2D(uSource, coord);
        gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
```

You are basically removing transparency information

To make this transparent you have to keep and maintain alpha between passes. The easy fix would be to set

`gl_FragColor.a = gl_FragColor.r`

Otherwise you can also for instance calculate luminance from rgb and use that as alpha.

So then `gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)` would work

P.s. few words how shader works: you can imagine there are two types of effects one are called screen space (thouse are post processing) and the 3d ones.
So for screen space effects you apply plane to your view and uv cords of that plane are cords of your screen, the gpu interpolates uv by amount of pixels and calculates in parallel 2d array of pixels, so then by uv coords or masks and so on… you calculate color of every pixel on screen 60 times per second…  Dunno if it makes sense but the simplest way to think about it that your vUv is a grid of pixels and you have to find color by checking or moving vUv

Comment: Thanks a lot for the awesome answers, helped me a lot to understand more the shaders. Just a little question, do you know how to change the color of the effect now ?  Because the problem is that my canvas is transparent and that's awesome, but the effect is barely visible due to its colors.

Comment: Ok so if your object color is black you can use something like gl_FragColor.a = 1 - gl_FragColor.r; this would set the black color to be not transparent.

Comment: Or you can use something like gl_FragColor.a = (gl_FragColor.r + gl_FragColor.g + gl_FragColor.b) / 3; this would give you average luminance (incorrect) for alpha…

Comment: There so many options, like you can even do something like that after you set alpha and you want to saturate it gl_FragColor.a *=gl_FragColor.a

Comment: I don't know if I was clear enough, but I don't want to change the canvas color anymore, but just the trail that the cursor leaves.